# Similar method in class

Tags: python, methods

I want to create two very similar methods in class.

The only diffrence in methods is a way of adding element to a `list`, other code stays the same.

```
class Test:
    a = []
    def test1(self):
        ...
        self.a.append('test1')
        ...

    def test2(self):
        ...
        self.insert(0, 'test2')
        ...

    def compute(self):
        while not self.is_answer:
            node = self.visited[0]
            for operator in self.order:
                next_node = node.next_node(operator)
                if (next_node and next_node not in self.computed
                        and next_node not in self.visited):
                    if next_node.check_answer():
                        self.is_answer = True
                        print('Answer found')
                        break
                    else:
                        self.visited.insert(0, next_node) <--- here I want change methods
            self.computed.append(self.visited.pop(0))
            self.depth += 1
```

Is there any cleaner way than copy paste code?

Comment: `self.insert(0, 'test2')` is a typo? It's hard to say with this small example, I don't see the issue with keeping them separate unless the methods were relatively substantial and differed on a small detail.

Comment: I have updated my question, does that help you?

Comment: Yes it works, but in case of many methods this if else statment will be long. Is there any way to pass this method as parameter without 'if'?

Comment: The `compute()` method calls both of the other methods—so it's unclear what you mean by "only diffrence in methods". Please [edit] your question and try to explain what you want more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your exact code looks like but you could do something like:

```
class Test:
   a = []
   def test1(self):
       self._similar_code()
       self.a.append('test1')

   def test2(self):
       self._similar_code()
       self.insert(0, 'test2')

   def _similar_code(self):
       pass
```

or

```
class Test:
   a = []
   def test(self, option):
       codetoexecute
       if (option):
           self.a.append('test1')
       else:
           self.insert(0, 'test2')
```

**Edit**

```
def compute(self, option):
    while not self.is_answer:
        node = self.visited[0]
        for operator in self.order:
            next_node = node.next_node(operator)
            if next_node and next_node not in self.computed and next_node not in self.visited:
                if next_node.check_answer():
                    self.is_answer = True
                    print('Answer found')
                    break
                else:
                    if (option):
                        self.visited.insert(0, next_node)
                    else:
                        self.visited.append(next_node)
        self.computed.append(self.visited.pop(0))
        self.depth += 1
```

Comment: This methods is nested with some loops and ifs. I added example in question.

Answer (score 0):

Make a method in the class for all the logic without inserting in the list. Name it with a leading underscore, as it should be considered private.

```
def _process (self):
    ...
    ...
```

Then:

```
def test1(self):
    self._process()
    self.a.append('test1')

def test2(self):
    self._process()
    self.insert(0, 'test2')
```

If you need to do things before and after the insertion, make two new methods.